# To Do List in javascript only: create,delete, update?

Tags: javascript, crud

I am creating a to do list only in JavaScript.
Html is like:

```
<section>
<input id="user_input" name="user_input" type="text" />
<button value="Add" id="add" onclick="addNotes()">Add</button>
<ul id="note_List"></ul>
</section>
```

JavaScript is like this, but I am doing something wrong. So please correct me, I am new to JS.

```
<script>
function addNotes() {
    var input = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
    if (input == "") {
        window.alert("You must enter a value in the New Task field.");
    }
    else {
        var noteList = document.getElementById('note_List');
        noteList.innerHTML += "<li>" + input + "<button id='delete'>clear</button> <span id='edit'>Edit</span></li>";
    }
}   
document.getElementById('delete').onclick = function () {
    var list = document.getElementById('delete');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has only two errors.
In the first place, you haven't closed the first function ("addNotes()"), before defining the onclick evento for "delete".

In the second place, your code is going to generate many elements with the same "id", which can be problematic. "Id"'s should be unique. Try defining "delete" as a class.

Then, use "getElementsByClassName" instead of "getElementById".

This is tricky. Or, instead of using any "delete" class, you can provide the "onclick" event directly to the generated button(s). For accessing and deleting (for instance) the "li" where the button "clear" is, you have to access its parent through a quite complicated call:

this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)

```
<script>
    function addNotes() {
        var input = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
        if (input == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter a value in the New Task field.");
        }
        else {
            var noteList = document.getElementById('note_List');
            noteList.innerHTML += "<li>" + input + "<button onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>clear</button> <span class='edit'>Edit</span></li>";
        }
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Great help!
I am sharing my js fiddle link: jsfiddle.net/a3Ly1xvr/3 could you please tell me how can I achieve the edit functionality ?

Comment: Hi. I have updated my solution. I use "prompt". Other possibility is to change the attribute "contenteditable" of the <li>, but that seems to be much more complicated. See it in: http://jsfiddle.net/a3Ly1xvr/7/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the addNotes function. You should always check the console in the browser which will always provide you with a clue as to where your code is wrong.

If you change your javascript code to this it works:

```
function addNotes() {
    var input = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
        if (input == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter a value in the New Task field.");
        }
        else {
            var noteList = document.getElementById('note_List');
            noteList.innerHTML += "<li>" + input + "<button id='delete'>clear</button> <span id='edit'>Edit</span></li>";
        }
}

document.getElementById('delete').onclick = function () {
            var list = document.getElementById('delete');
   }
```